# custom error text with alignment in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

i am adding content padding in to textfield. but not need padding in error text.

```
child: TextFormField(
              controller: _text,
              keyboardType: widget.inputType,
              onSaved: widget.onSaveData,
              validator: widget.validator,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: _focus_bg,
                filled: true,
                hintText: widget.hintText,
                contentPadding:
                    new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                //contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 11, right: 3, top: 14, bottom: 14),
                errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, height: 0.3),

                border:
                    OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    borderSide:
                        new BorderSide(color: AppColor.textBorderFocused)),
              ),
              focusNode: _textFieldFocus,
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to control the error text padding, however a work-around has been provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654017/flutter-is-it-possible-to-change-textformfield-errortext-padding).